# my final step in the rails app, how to make comments appear in a popup?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html, facebox

This is the last remaining item to complete my first rails app and need some help. 
On each user profile (localhost:3000/users/username), there's a listing of posts that the user has made. Associated with each post are comments. So post_id: 3 could have comments.

I have it working already in view form but I need the comments to appear in a popup instead when the "Comments" link under each post is clicked. 
I have already applied facebox which is a jQuery-based lightbox that displays popups.

I just need to move what's currently shown in show.html.erb into a popup.

There's the _comment_form.html.erb which renders into _post.html.erb

```
  <%= link_to #, :rel => "facebox-#{post.id}" do %>
  +<%= post.comments.count.to_s %>
<% end %>
 <div class ="ItemComments"><% if post.comments.exists? %>
   <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
   <%= image_tag("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=#{Digest::MD5::hexdigest(comment.user.email)}" %>
   <span class="users"><%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %></span>
   <span class="timestamp"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</span>
   <span class="content2"><%= comment.comment_content %></span>
   <% end %>
 <% end %></div>
```

The above renders into _post.html.erb using:

```
<%= render 'shared/comment_form', post: post if signed_in?%>
```

Then it renders into show.html.erb

I'm trying to use this line, but what do I link it to?

```
    <%= link_to #, :rel => "facebox-#{post.id}" do %>
  +<%= post.comments.count.to_s %>
<% end %>
```

This is shared/_comment.html.erb

```
<% if post.comments.exists? %>
  <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= image_tag("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar") %>
    <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %>
            <span class="timestamp"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</span>
    <span class="content2"><%= comment.comment_content %></span>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I created a new thread with more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421425/only-the-comments-of-the-last-post-are-displayed-in-popup-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to render your comments into a hidden div and give that div an id. Next you point your link to the id of the div using # followed by the id. It would look something like this:

_post.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "#comments", :rel => "facebox" do %>
    <%= post.comments.count.to_s %>
<% end %>
<div id="comments">
    <%= render 'shared/comment_form', post: post if signed_in?%>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#comments {
    display: none;
}
```

See the 'Divs' heading over at the [Facebox docs](http://defunkt.io/facebox/).

Comment: I tried but I'm having some trouble. Is it possible to use the full code that is inside _comment.html.erb and hide it inside a div or does this only work if rendered?

Comment: You want to render all your comments inside the hidden div. Did I understand you correctly in that the 'shared/comment_form' partial also renders the actual comments? If not then adjust my answer so that you render all your comments inside the #comments div.

Comment: I made it so I render this between the <div> tags: <%= render 'shared/comment', post: post if signed_in? %>. I made it so 'shared/_comment.html.erb contains just the actual comments (updated my original post above). But I'm getting blanks when I try to get the popup. I tried with "TEST" in between the <div> tags and it works so any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: That sounds odd, have you checked with Firebug/Chrome inspector if the comments are actually getting rendered inside the hidden div?

Comment: Firebug is an extension for Firefox. If you are using Chrome or Safari you have something similar built in. Right click inside your page and select "Inspect element" and you'll get the inspector. From there you can navigate through the DOM structure of the page (your html-tags). Find your #comments div and you can see if it has any comments inside it.

Please read up on Firebug/Chrome inspector, they are invaluable when dealing with web development.

Comment: I found out that it does pull the comments in. The only problem is that, the same comments show up for all of the popups. The same comments that popup are from the most recent post of a user. So if the most recent post has 2 comments, these same 2 comments come up in all of the popups. Do you know how I can make sure that this doesn't happen? I feel that I'm close.

Comment: I created a new thread with this issue and included more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421425/only-the-comments-of-the-last-post-are-displayed-in-popup-ruby-on-rails