# only the comments of the last post are displayed in popup (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have comments under each post. All of the posts and the comments can be seen through link /users/username

I'm using facebox (jQuery-based lightbox) for the popups and the comments are displaying just fine. The only problem is that only the comments of the LATEST post are shown in the popups. The **same** comments are displayed for all of the popup links.

For example, if the latest post has 5 comments, I can click the comments link below the post to view that in a popup. However, when I scroll down and go to another post with 1 comment, I see the same 5 comments when I click the comment link. How can I make sure that only the comments associated to a particular post is displayed?

Here's my show.html.erb

```
<script src="/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/src/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/src/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script language="javascript">

 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
}) 
</script>

<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
     </section>
  <br>
  </aside>
 <br>

  <div class="span10">
    <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3>Browse</h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  </div>
```

My micropost.html.erb where the comment view is at the bottom

```
<li>

 <%= render 'shared/comment_form', micropost: micropost if signed_in?%>
 <div id ="modal" class = "comments">
  <% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= image_tag("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=#{Digest::MD5::hexdigest(comment.user.email)}", :alt => 'Avatar', :class => 'avatar', :height => "10%", :width => "10%") %> <!-- Retrieves Gravatar -->
    <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %>
          <span class="timestamp"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</span>
    <span class="content2"><%= comment.comment_content %></span>
    <% end %></div>
</li>
```

Then finally the comment_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([micropost, @comment]) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :comment_content %>
  </div>
  <div class="ItemContainer">
<div class="ItemInput">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">
    Comment
  </button>
  </div><div class="ItemCommentCount">
<% end %>

<%= link_to "#modal", :rel => "facebox-#{micropost.id}" do %>
  Comments
<% end %></div></div>
```

Comment: I did try cutting and pasting all of the lines under <div id="modal"> into show.html.erb but I still see only the same comments from the latest post in all of the popups

Comment: To clarify, my show.html.erb (final rendered HTML) renders in _micropost.html.erb which has the <div id="modal">

Comment: Look at the HTML that the browser ends up rendering and tell me how many `<div id="model">` elements there are. HTML `id` attributes **must** be unique within each page, if you have duplicate `id` attributes then you will have problems.

Comment: I look through Chrome inspect element and I looked inside <ol class="microposts"> as that's where the information for <div id="modal"> is.  Each micropost is cased inside <li> tags and they all have the same <div id="modal">. How can I make them unique?

Answer (score 0):

From the [fine specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id):

> **id = ID**
>
> A unique identifier for the element.
>
> There must not be multiple elements in a document that have the same id value.

You have multiple `<div id="modal">` elements:

```
<div id ="modal" class = "comments">
```

in your page. Since `id`s are supposed to be unique, a DOM search for an `id` will usually only find the first one; you're always getting the comments for the first micropost and that matches the expected behavior when you have duplicate `id`s.

An easy solution would be to include the `micropost.id` in the DOM `id`s:

```
<div id="modal-<%= micropost.id %>" class="comments">
```

and then in the links:

```
<%= link_to "#modal-#{micropost.id}", :rel => "facebox-#{micropost.id}" do %>
  Comments
<% end %>
```